# CMFCPopupMenu Stays In the Background in Win7

Tags: c++, mfc, system-tray, tray

I'm trying some of the new MFC functionality and i want the same thing that the TrayMenu project from Visual C++ Language Samples for Visual Studio 2010 does but in my machine (don't know if is only in my machine i try to find the same problem in the web but didn't find any similar report!!!) the menu appears in the background of the new win7 traynotifywwnd, and i can't seem to put it work right:

The code is simple:

```
void CTrayMenuDlg::OnTrayContextMenu ()
{
      CPoint point;
      ::GetCursorPos (&point);

      CMenu menu;
      menu.LoadMenu (IDR_MENU1);

      CMFCPopupMenu::SetForceShadow (TRUE);

      HMENU hMenu = menu.GetSubMenu (0)->Detach ();
      CMFCPopupMenu* pMenu = theApp.GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopupMenu(hMenu, point.x, point.y, this, TRUE);

      pMenu->SetForegroundWindow ();
 }
```

I think that SetForegroundWindow is some how a fix for this problem, but it does not work, it stills show bewind the window where all the tray icon are hidden and displayed when we click in the little arrow (note that if the icon is displayed in the ToolbarWindow32 -not hidden - and we call the tray context menu then it all works fine, this problem only appear if the icon is hidden and is show using the little arrow in the ToolbarWindow32 and a window is displayed with the hidden icons - is this window that stays in front of my context menu...)

[image: context menu shown behind popup window]

Has anyone find this problem? and there is any solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I see the same problem, so I edited your question to add a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Nuno, few days back i also faced the same problem. To solve this i used SetForegroundWindow(hParent). where hParent is the window handle passed during the creation of system tray. please let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Hi, no SetForegroundWindow does not work for me...

Comment: Try to run the application as Administrator or with UAC disabled. May be this is a problem of permissions. And try that also with the SetWindowPos code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this one but you can try adding:

```
    // Set window position to topmost window.
    pMenu->SetWindowPos(
                &CWnd::wndTopMost,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_NOSIZE );
```

instead of  pMenu->SetForegroundWindow ();

Comment: Yep already tried, but with no success too, the problem is that when the menu has popup menus then the first one will be the top most one and not the new popup menu...

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-AT/library/bb983878%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Add `::SetWindowPos(pMenu->m_hWnd,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);`
>   before the `pMenu->SetForegroundWindow ();`
>   in `CTrayMenuDlg::OnTrayContextMenu ()` function.

For me this worked!